# How to execute code on a change in a instance variable?

Tags: python, event-handling

I have an instance variable from a class and I want to execute some code when there is a change in my variable.

I'm aware of the property and Observer pattern event handling but I don't think it helps in my case.

Example:

```
class Thing:
  def __init__(self):
      self.thing = []
      self.thing2 = ""
  def code_that_executes(self):
      self.thing2 = self.thing[0]
s = Thing()
s.thing.append("Something") #The event
```

Comment: this question needs more context; what framework are you using if any? is this a script or part of an application? is the 'event' you're referring to generated client side or server side?

Comment: what about adding the event in def append of Thing1, so when you call append("Something") it executes?

Comment: @PyNoob I'm not using a framework and I think i misused the word "event". The event in this case is when the instance variable self.thing appends. I'll change the example so that it narrows down to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement **setattr** on your class. Here is an example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = 5
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == "A":
            print("A has changed to: {0}".format(value))
```

Now when you have an object `foo = Foo()` and call `foo.bar = 5` you get the result:

```
bar changed to 5
```

See [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**setattr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)

Note:This will print during the **init** call as well.